# Movieplayer navigation bar frame issue in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app, I recorded a video & play it through MpMovie Player. It seems works fine.

But when i play video, The navigation bar(default  progress bar) is come down rather than join with status bar.

[image: See Navigation bar]

**My code to play video is as follow**

```
-(IBAction)mth_play:(id)sender
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *VidLibrary = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSString *url = [VidLibrary stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"p.mp4"];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *pv=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(playfinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[pv moviePlayer]];
    MPMoviePlayerController *pc=[pv moviePlayer];

    [self.view addSubview:pv.view];
    [pc play];
}
```

**How to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why you added the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`'s `view` as a subview?

You can show the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` modally instead:

```
[self presentViewController:pv animated:YES completion:nil]; // iOS 5+
```

or

```
[self presentModalViewController:pv animated:YES]; // technically deprecated in iOS 6
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Hide navigation bar.
2. Set pv frame 0,0